# Scroll DOM node to top of screen in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I've got this render function in React that create a DOM element

```
public render(): JSX.Element {
        return <div className={"card " + (this.props.expanded ? "expanded " : "") + (this.props.className ? this.props.className : "")} >
            <div className="card-container">
                {React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child, index) => {
                    if (!React.isValidElement(child)) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (child.type === CardSummary) {
                        return React.cloneElement(child, this.newSummaryProps(child));
                    }
                    return child;
                })}
            </div>
        </div>;
    }
```

This render something to the DOM like:

[image]

What do I need to do in the React.Component to be able to return the "card expanded" DOM node to the console.

I would like that node to scroll to the top of the screen if it is out of viewport. Thanks for your time and interest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return <div className={"card " + (this.props.expanded ? "expanded " : "") + (this.props.className ? this.props.className : "")} 
        ref={this.props.expanded ? elem=>elem.scrollIntoView()||elem=>elem}>
            <div className="card-container">
                {React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child, index) => {
                    if (!React.isValidElement(child)) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (child.type === CardSummary) {
                        return React.cloneElement(child, this.newSummaryProps(child));
                    }
                    return child;
                })}
            </div>
        </div>;
    }
```

Comment: what does ref= refer to?

Comment: They allow you to obtain DOM references to the leaf nodes. See [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). They also allow you to obtain instance references to non-leaf nodes.

Comment: when I console log elem, it says undefined. Are you sure React knows that elem = the DOM element?

Comment: It does. If its not happening in your case, could you please share a more complete code repo? Thanks